# WooCommerce cart subtotal: Display 'free' instead of '0,00'

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, hook-woocommerce

i am searching for a solution to display 'free' instead of €0,00 in the WooCommerce Cart/Checkout.

I know, there is a snippet for the Single Produkt itself, but is there a possibillity to change the price label even in the Subtotal/total calulation on the checkout/cart page?

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'price_free_zero_empty', 9999, 2 );
   
function price_free_zero_empty( $price, $product ){
    if ( '' === $product->get_price() || 0 == $product->get_price() ) {
        $price = '<span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">FREE</span>';
    }  
    return $price;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use the following that should display "Free" when the product price is equal to Zero:

```
// Cart and minicart
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_price', 'change_cart_item_price_html', 10, 3 );
function change_cart_item_price_html( $price_html, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) {
    if( $cart_item['data']->get_price() == 0 ) {
        return '<span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">'.__("FREE", "woocommerce").'</span>';
    }
    return $price_html;
}

// Cart and Checkout
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_subtotal', 'change_checkout_item_subtotal_html', 10, 3 );
function change_checkout_item_subtotal_html( $subtotal_html, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) {
    if( $cart_item['data']->get_price() == 0 ) {
        return '<span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">'.__("FREE", "woocommerce").'</span>';
    }
    return $subtotal_html;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). It should works.