# Hide Price In Woocommerce Cart For Products With Prices Below A Certain Amount

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am looking for a way to hide product price for products with a price that is below 10 in a woocommerce cart. I can hide the price before adding to cart with `woocommerce_get_price_html` but the price reappears in cart.

I have also tried the code below but no success

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_price', 'replace_zero_with_string', 10, 3 );
function replace_zero_with_string( $price, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) {

    if ( $cart_item[ 'data' ]->price < 10 ) {
        $price = __( 'Enquire', 'astra' );
    }

    return $price;
}
```

As a side note: In case a cart has a product with a price below 10, I filter away the payment gateways and only leave a custom quote request gateway. Now I just need a way to somehow hide the price.

Comment: The following answered your question: [WooCommerce cart subtotal: Display 'free' instead of '0,00'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63995559/woocommerce-cart-subtotal-display-free-instead-of-0-00). 
I have provided some references in your previous (same question) and you just deleted and reposted your question.

Comment: My last question was not clear, I needed to hide the price everywhere. Plus for some reason my code never worked. Am more curious to know why it didn't work.